# changed needed while switching to base64 representation from pdf representation

Tags: java, spring, base64

I have a controller which is generating a PDF on the browser when I use the following link :

`http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/boxlabelpdf.htm`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("boxlabelpdf")
public class BoxLabelPdfController {

  private MyLocationManager mgr;

  public void setMyLocationManager(MyLocationManager MyLocationManager) {
    this.mgr = MyLocationManager;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView view(ModelAndView mav, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws Exception {

    List < MyLocation > results = mgr.getMyLocationByClassQuery("id = 90");
   
   JasperReport jr = PdfReportUtils.getReportTemplate("BoxLabels");
    byte[] reportBytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jr, new HashMap < > (),
      new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(results));

    System.out.println("converting reportBytes byte array tp Base64 inside BoxLabelPdfController");
    String encoded = Base64Utils.encodeToString(reportBytes);

    System.out.println(encoded);

    // output to screen
    PdfReportUtils.outputReport(response, reportBytes);
    // nothing to forward to - already sent the pdf to the browser
    return null;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

The `PdfReportUtils` class has this function which is called above and is responsible for sending the byte array to webbrowser and I see a pdf when I put the following URL on the web browser :

`http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/boxlabelpdf.htm`

```
/**
     * Outputs the byte array passed to it to the web browser
     */
    public static void outputReport(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] resultBytes) throws IOException {

        if (resultBytes != null) {
            ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            int conLength = resultBytes.length;

            response.setContentType(MimeConstant.PDF_MIME.getContentType().toString());
            //The following is present inside MimeConstant class for above declaration of setContentType:
            //public static final MimeConstant PDF_MIME = new MimeConstant("pdf-generic", "application/pdf");

            Date date = new Date();
            String fileName = "MyReport" + Utils.getDateAsYYYYMMDD(date) + Utils.getAsHHmmss(date);
            response.setContentLength(conLength);
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
            servletOutputStream.write(resultBytes);

            servletOutputStream.flush();
            servletOutputStream.close();
        } else {
            // no pages to output - just error msg
            // output new html page
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>No PDF Pages</title>");
            out.println("</head>");

            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<br/>");
            out.println("No PDF Pages were generated for this report ");
            out.println("<br/>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

I would like to send Base64Utils.encodeToString(reportBytes) to the web browser when I click the link `http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/boxlabelpdf.htm`

Do I need to change the setContentType and other things inside outputReport function to something else since it's a base64 coded string now?

Reason I'm switching to base64 is because I want to use it on client side like mentioned in [this document][1]:

```
var config = qz.configs.create("Printer Name");
var data = [{ 
   type: 'pixel',
   format: 'pdf',
   flavor: 'base64',
   data: 'Ck4KcTYwOQpRMjAzLDI2CkI1LDI2LDAsMUEsMyw3LDE1MixCLCIxMjM0IgpBMzEwLDI2LDAsMywx...' 
}];
qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
```

So in my code, I can just specify `data:boxlabelpdf.htm` and that should give me the encoded string by calling the controller.
[1]: https://qz.io/docs/pixel#base64-pdf

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that while preparing data, I can't use `boxlabelpdf.htm` as `data:boxlabelpdf.htm` with `flavor:pdf` . So I am switching to base64 representation and in order to get the `data: <base64encoded string here>` for `flavor: 'base64'`, I would probably need to have my controller send it in base64 format and then the next task is to figure out how to retrieve it once it's sent to the browser so that I can use it while preparing `data`. I think what you are asking is not something t oworry about now.

Comment: I believe you are referring to this part `var printData = [
            { type: 'pixel', format: 'pdf', flavor: 'file', data: 'assets/pdf_sample.pdf', options: opts }
        ];`  from my previous question ?

Comment: Those two are unrelated. The one I mentioned above was provided in the sample.html from the QZ Tray website. I'm trying to figure out how can I use my htm generated pdf in that place.